# Visual Studio 2015 displays controls without 3D effects

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

For some reason, VS 2015 is showing checkboxes, radiobuttons, etc. with a flat look:
[image: Flat look controls]

Is there a way to make them look like this:

[image]

This is after just starting a new project with however it is initially setup.  I'm running Windows 10.  Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps this happens because this is Windows 10's standard look?

Comment: Is there a way to get the old look?

Comment: Define "old look".

Comment: Are you using WinForms? Add the tag if so. Look at the `FlatStyle` property of the controls.

Comment: A standard Windows Forms application, yes.  Add what tag?  I have looked at FlatStyle.  It appears this is just how it looks in Windows 10.

Comment: He wanted you to add the WinForms tag to the question. Here, I've done it.

Comment: Yeah, Windows 10 uses a flatter appearance for the common controls. Check elsewhere in the system UI for an example.

Comment: That's the Window 7 look. For that you must either add the old Windows 7 theme to your computer or find a Windows 7 .NET theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Windows 95/98 "old look" you can disable the use of Visual Styles in your application:

1. Right-click your project in the `Solution Explorer` and press `Properties`.
2. Go to the `Application` tab and untick `Enable XP visual styles`.

Comment: I tried that; however, if you do that, then you can't use any styles.  SetWindowTheme won't work at all without it.

Comment: @JoeOliphant : What style do you actually want then? Can you show us a picture?

Comment: I edited the question.  I apparently didn't ask correctly so I got admonished.